# deserialize Json into POJO

Tags: java, json, jackson, jackson2

I am trying to convert the following JSON structure (part of a larger JSON object) to a POJO but getting the exception copied below (using Java/Jackson).

**JSON**

```
"outputKeys":
{"ABC":"gGyIioUr4Jfr5QiCm6Z==",
"DEF":"RxHfNyD2JyPOpG5tv3Jaj5g=="}
```

**Java class**

```
    private class OutputKeys {

        private String key;
        private String value;

        public OutputKeys(String key, String value) {
            this.key = key;
            this.value = value;
        }
}
```

&

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.readValue(jsonString, Test.class);
```

**exception:**

```
no suitable constructor found, can not deserialize from Object value (missing default constructor or creator, or perhaps need to add/enable type information?
```

Test class has the OutputKeys as an attribute.
Any suggestions would be welcome.  I have tried using a List of OutputKeys as well .

Update:

I have tried the following without success:

```
class OutputKeys {
public Map<String, String> keys;
///with constructor/setter/getters
}
```

&

```
class OutputKeys {
public List<OutputKey> keys;
///with constructor/setter/getters

   public class OutputKey {

        Map<String, String> outputs = new HashMap<>();
// tried this too:
// String key
//String value

}
```

Comment: Did you try to create default constructor (constructor with arguments)  and please could you add a code that we can test (main class and all related class  )

Comment: `OutputKeys` should contain a `Map<String, String>` based on the example JSON, no?

Comment: @MickMnemonic i tried that earlier, I get the same exception

Comment: what should be the values of the attributes of one instance of `OutputKeys`? is it `key="ABC"`, `value="gGyIioUr4Jfr5QiCm6Z=="` or is it `key="gGyIioUr4Jfr5QiCm6Z=="`, `value="RxHfNyD2JyPOpG5tv3Jaj5g=="` ?? in other words, how do you map a 2-entry map into a class with two Strings?

Comment: @SharonBenAsher the key names are dynamically assigned i.e. in one instance ,the key names could be ABC, in another DEF & GHI, and in another JKL and MNO etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the keys were dynamic, I ended up deserializing the data using the iterator on the JsonNode:

```
jsonNode.get("outputKeys").iterator()
```

& then getting the relevant dynamic key information via the iterator.

Answer (score 0):

You require below mentioned single class only, containing

1. All keys(ABC and DEF)
2. getters/setters
3. toString() which you'll use interact with JSON.

   public class OutputKeys
   {
       private String ABC;

   ```
   private String DEF;

   public String getABC ()
   {
       return ABC;
   }

   public void setABC (String ABC)
   {
       this.ABC = ABC;
   }

   public String getDEF ()
   {
       return DEF;
   }

   public void setDEF (String DEF)
   {
       this.DEF = DEF;
   }

   @Override
   public String toString()
   {
       return "ClassPojo [ABC = "+ABC+", DEF = "+DEF+"]";
   }
   ```

   }

Let me know if you require more details.

Comment: also, the ABC and DEF part are dynamic- not static

Answer (score -1):

I needed a similar tool for NodeJS. So that I can write tests on parts of a bigger model that was serialized (JSON).

So, if I need only "ABC":"gGyIioUr4Jfr5QiCm6Z==" or "XYZ":{"Hello": "My String", "Content": [1,2,3]}, the only property I care to test at the moment is:

`var sutXYX = { Hello: "My String", Content: [ 1, 2, 2]};`

I wrote this tool as a utility https://github.com/whindes/PojoScriptifyFromJSON